# Problems estimating a "Bayesian version of FIML"

Tags: regression, bayesian, missing-data, data-imputation, stan

I am anticipating that my question exposes some basic ignorance about how mcmc works, but here we go:

In an attempt to deal with missing data I am trying to simultaneously estimate a regression model as well as the co-variance of the variables in the regression model and some auxiliary variables. (Which I think is similar to what full information maximum likelihood [FIML] is doing, [though FIML does not impute data](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.459.6288&rep=rep1&type=pdf).)

To be specific: Assume matrix $X$ has the columns $y,e,m,el$, the last entry being the product of variables $e$ and $l$. Column $y$ has missing values.

I want to estimate the effect of $e$ on $y^i$. To deal with missing data I also estimate the co-variance matrix of $X^i$, where $y^i$ and $X^i$ are vector/matrix with imputed values. After successfully implementing such a model in the R package [lavaan](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/lavaan/index.html), I am now having problems with a Bayesian version.

Specifically, one can write up such a model in the probabilistic programming language [Stan](https://mc-stan.org/) as follows:

```
data {
  int N;
  int K;
  vector[N] y;
  vector[N] m;
  vector[N] e;
  vector[N] el;
  int nmiss;
  int missidx[nmiss];
}
parameters {
  real intercept;
  real b;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
  corr_matrix[K] Omega;
  vector[K] mu;
  vector<lower=0>[K] tau;
  vector[nmiss] yimp;
}
transformed parameters {
  cov_matrix[K] Sigma = quad_form_diag(Omega,tau);
} 
model {
  // omitting priors to keep this shorter
  vector[N] yl = y;
  yl[missidx] = yimp;
  // regression
  target += normal_lpdf(yl | intercept + e*b,sigma);
  // covariance
  for (n in 1:N) {
    vector[K] vec = to_vector({yl[n],e[n],el[n],m[n]});
    target += multi_normal_lpdf(vec | mu, Sigma);
  }
}
```

When I try to estimate this model, I can't simultaneously estimate the regression weight for $e$ and the covariance matrix. There is some "interference" (for the lack of a better term) which makes that the regression weight for $e$ and the variance of $e$ in the variance-covariance matrix for $X$ are underestimated.

I can "hack around" this problem by multiplying the log posterior of the covariance `multi_normal_lpdf(vec | mu, Sigma)` with a large number. This works intuitively because it gives precedence to the estimation of the co-variation between all variables and thus estimates the effect of $e$ on $y$ based on imputed data with the right covariance.

However, I assume others must have thought deeper about this and would be glad about any pointer or comment.
I'd also be happy about a pointer to some pseudo-code for FIML estimation, because I am not sure I am understanding the details directly.

Comment: I'd recommend asking this question on the dedicated Stan forums: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/ - there are many Stan experts there that don't look here as much. Good luck!

Comment: @MauritsM : I have already asked this question on the Stan forum. I am re-posting it hear, because I think this is a general issue with Bayesian estimation of the model, given that a FIML estimation of the model works as intended.